# One form input to set two database values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form which when submitted creates a new record in a database. I have two values in the database, value_1 & value_2. In the form there is an input field for value_1 which is a dropdown value of yes and no. When the form is submitted I wish to have value_1 and value_2 set to the value selected in the input field for value_1. So if dropdown for value_1 is set to yes then value_2 is also set to yes.

I am currently using the following but believe there must be a more elegant solution:

```
params[:person][:free] = params[:person][:trial]
@person = Person.new(params[:person])
@person.update_attribute(:free, params[:person][:free])
```

Comment: Since you are creating Person after changing the value of params[:person][:free], I dont think you need that last line. you can just save @person.

Comment: Strangely i thought the same but it wasnt updating therefore had to add this the update in. Ended up refining it to `@person.update_attribute(:free, params[:person][:trial])` as dont see the point in assigning a value to `params[:person][:free]` if its not taking effect on `Person.new`

Comment: Can you put a `p params[:person]` after first line and see in rails console what value it is showing ?

Comment: Yes and it is incorrect. Think I will leave it as is as it is working. Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First you should think about what you really want. What is your logic.
Do you want value_2 always equal to value_1? I hope not, because in this case u absolutely no  need a second column in your database.
Do you want value_2 equal to value_1 only the creation of a new record but allow it to be edited after that? In this case you should put the logic in your model with a callback :

In your model add :

```
before_create :set_value_2

private

def set_value_2
  self.value_2 = value_1
end
```

The private statement is because you don't want anybody to access the method outside the model itself.